# How to avoid data leaks when using Zustand with NextJs?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, zustand

There are some problems when working with Zustand and NextJs that are associated with unexpected behavior of the application. Due to the fact that each zustand store is essentially a singleton, this leads to unexpected behavior in the node, for example, that an unauthorized user at some point in time may have a page rendered based on the state of another authorized user. Are there any solutions to this problem? So far I only see recommendations for wrapping all repositories in context

original issue https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/discussions/2200

```js
// useCatalogListingStore.ts

const useCatalogListingStore = create<ICatalogListingState>()(() => {
  return {
    listing: [],
  }
)

// page/index.tsx
function Page() {
  const listing = useCatalogListingStore(state => state.listing);
  
  return <pre>{ JSON.stringify(listing)}</pre>
} 

export default Page;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const categoryId = context.query.categoryId;

  const categoryApiService = new CategoryApiService(categoryId);
  const listing = await categoryApiService.getList();

  useCatalogListingStore.setState({listing}); // here is useCatalogListingStore is module-level variable, that define once in build time and not changed by anytime in runtime, so for different users it can be same variable that leading to bugs

  return { props: {} };
}
```

so the solution is not using `useCatalogListinStore` as variables in server side, instead create for each request new store and set data.

Like that https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/initialize-state-with-props#basic-component-usage

But how can I use the `.setState`-call at store, when my store saved in react-context?

Comment: Can you share a code example of what you are trying to achieve? As discussed in the github thread, Zustand can not be used in React Server components. However it can of course be used in client components. (If the difference between the two is not yet fully clear to you, I'd recommend to research on that first)

Comment: @Giraphi i'm trying to use zustand with nextjs without /app dir (app router)

Comment: @Giraphi upd code example